# Flutter Firebase Storage || Quotas and billing for images

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

Sorry for the dumb question, I've already searched the web but i'm not very sure about it.

When using `Firebase Storage`, let's say that i have stored some images:

1. If i use `NetworkImage(url)` for showing that images, does that count as download for billing?
2. If so, should I implement some version control to save images in local and on start checking the versions of the images to download or not?
3. And last, if so, getting metadata for checking version also does count as download or read?

Thanks in advance. Instructions for `Firebase Database` are clear, but for `Storage` i really don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Downloading the data needs to read the file and transfer the data, so it counts as those two (charged) operations.
2. If you want to prevent redownloading the same data, you should indeed implement some caching scheme in the client.
3. Yes. Checking the metadata counts as a read operation, but it'll incur lower charges for the downloaded data (as you're not downloading the bytes of the file itself).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I very appreciate it the answer.